# Maximum Likelihood solution of a zero-covariance process

Tags: estimation, least-squares

Let the measurement model be:

$\tilde{y}=Hx+v$

$\tilde{y}=H\hat{x}+e$

where $H$ is the basis matrix, $v$ is a constant vector equal to, say, $a$, $x$ is the measurement variable and $e$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random vector. Let $H=[1\:1\:1\dots]$. The Maximum Likelihood Estimation solution is to minimize:

$J(\hat{x})=\frac{1}{2}[\tilde{y}-H\hat{x}]^TR^{-1}[\tilde{y}-H\hat{x}]$

where $R=cov(\tilde{y})=E\{(\tilde{y}-\mu)(\tilde{y}-\mu)^T\}=E\{(Hx+a-Hx-a)(Hx+a-Hx-a)^T\}=0$

I don't see how a solution exist when the covariance is zero. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to the likelihood of $\tilde{y}$ given $\hat{x}$? if so, the likelihood given $\hat{x}$ is of a the residual $e$, which has some [predetermined] variance, so $R$ is just $\sigma_e^2 I$.

Comment: $\hat{x}$ is the estimated values, $x$ is the true values (unknown). The Maximum Likelihood refers to $L(\tilde{y}|x)$

Comment: If it is given $x$, then $Hx$ is just a shift in the mean, and the covariance is just that of the noise, i.e. a scalar matrix with the variance of the noise on the diagonal.

Comment: Can you, please, write this as an answer and with explicit equations so that I don't misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the following forward model: $y=Hx+e$, where $e\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I)$ is an independent noise, and $x$ has some possibly unknown distribution.
The likelihood function of $y$ given $x$ is:
$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = f_{Y|X}(Hx+e|x)$, which, given $x$, renders $Hx$ to be "deterministic", and therefore this is the density of an i.i.d Gaussian vector, with nonzero mean: $\mathcal{N}(Hx,\sigma^2I)$.

Therefore, the maximum likelihood, $\hat{x}=\arg\max_x f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, is given by 
$$\hat{x}=\arg\min \frac{1}{2}(y-Hx)^T(\sigma^2I)^{-0.5}(y-Hx) $$
$$\hat{x}=\arg\min \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-Hx)^T(y-Hx):=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\Vert y-Hx \Vert^2 .$$

Comment: if you are looking for the likelihood, then it is given the correct value, i.e. $x$. It yields the likelihood of a measurement, $y$, given some true $x$ value. 
Or, possibly, I didn't understand the formulation of the problem.

Comment: Can we compute $\sigma^2$?

Comment: If you want to estimate the noise variance, you will need to know something about the distribution of $x$. For instance, you can use ML estimation: $\hat{\sigma^2}=\arg\max P(y|\sigma^2)=\arg\max P(Hx+e|\sigma^2)$, where you need to be able to calculate the distribution of $Hx+e$.